# How can i get my table filled automatically when i gave id from another table in ax 2009

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a two tables in first table i filled the values with name id,

on second table if i gave the id the table needs to fill the name automatically, how can i do this please help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide code as to what you have tried and try to edit your question as to not be so broad

Comment: axsl.TransDate=DateTimeUtil::utcNow();

Comment: showing error in tat coding as Operand types are not compatible with the operator.

i tried to display current date in the field transdate..

Comment: wat my question is i need to fill the details automatically when I enter an id

Comment: Ok, slow down, take a look at [ask] and [edit] any relevant information in the comments into your question. You also may want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You commented that the error is in the following line:

```
axsl.TransDate = DateTimeUtil::utcNow();
```

This is logic because `axsl.TransDate` is `Date` and `DateTimeUtil::utcNow()` return a `UtcDateTime` when you compile get this error **Operand types are not compatible with the operator.**

There are many ways to fix this error.

***Try this:***

```
axsl.TransDate = DateTimeUtil::date(DateTimeUtil::utcNow())
```

`DateTimeUtil::date()` convert `UtcDateTime` in `Date`.

or you can use `today()` method to return the actual date.

Comment: I have following tables : AX_BookMaster with book name, id, author name, pages, isbn num

Comment: Subscriber table with subscriber id, name and address
I have the subscriberlines in another table with fields SubscriberId,BookId and transdate as today date.

Comment: I create relation in subscriberline table to bookid and subscriber id.


Now I created another table as Transaction table to mention the tobereturndate of the book and status as checkin, checkout..

Comment: When the book is subscribed it need to change the status as checkout and when it is returned it need to change as checkin.
in transaction table i tried to write the modified field coding as you mentioned:

Comment: public void modifiedField(fieldId _fieldId)
{
AX_SubscriberLine axsl;
AX_BookMaster axb;
;
super(_fieldId);
switch(_fieldId)
{
case fieldnum(AX_Transaction,Book_Id):
select axsl where axsl.Book_Id==this.Book_Id;
this.Sub_Id=axsl.Sub_Id;
this.TransDate=axsl.TransDate;
break;

case fieldNum(AX_Transaction, ToBeReturnDate):
while select pages from axb where axb.Book_Id==this.Book_Id
{
if(axb.Pages>'1000')
this.TobeReturnDate= axsl.TransDate+(4*7);
else
this.TobeReturnDate=axsl.TransDate+(2*7);
}
break;
}
but it is not getting the return date please give me the exact coding

Comment: The return date is based on book pages if the page is less than 1000 user can return after 4 weeks, if it is less than 1000 user need to return with in 2 weeks.

Comment: also in subscriberline table user can't subscribe more than 4 books so i write validation as

Comment: public boolean validateWrite()
{
    boolean ret;
    AX_SubscriberLine axs;
    ;
    ret = super();
    while select count(Sub_Id) from axs
    if(axs.Sub_Id>='4')
    warning("User can't subscriber more than 4 books");
    return ret;
}

But it is throwing warning but storing the record in table

Comment: It is very complex to help you with this scenario of comments. Please add a new question and explain this scenario. Also edit this question and mark the answer like correct so other users can be useful. Thanks.